# AngularJs get count of element by class name

Tags: angularjs

How can I count element by class name in angularJs?

I have tried with:

```
$scope.numItems = function() {
    $window.document.getElementsByClassName("yellow").length;
};
```

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ndCqpZaALfOEiYieepcn?p=preview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have defined your function correctly, but made a mistake in showing its results: it should have been...

```
<p>{{numItems()}}</p>
```

... instead of plain `{{numItems}}`. You want to display the *return value* of the function, and not the function itself (that's meaningless), that's why you should follow the standard JS syntax for a function invocation.

Note that you can send arguments into this expression too: for example, I've rewritten that method like this:

```
$scope.numItems = function(className) {
   return $window.document.getElementsByClassName(className).length;
};
```

... and then made three different counters in the template:

```
  <p>Yellow: {{numItems('yellow')}}</p>
  <p>Green: {{numItems('green')}}</p>
  <p>Red: {{numItems('red')}}</p>
```

[**Plunker Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/dnw88VGEfOFhHF3LbA8y?p=preview).

---

But here's the real problem: `numItems()` result, used in one View, is based on DOM traversal - in other words, on another View. Not only that goes against Angular philosophy in general, it tends to break. In fact, it DOES break since [this commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/667183a8c79d6ffce571a2be78c05dc76503b222), as old as 1.3.0:

> Now, even when the ngAnimate module is not used, if `$rootScope` is in
>   the midst of a digest, class manipulation is deferred. This helps
>   reduce jank in browsers such as IE11.

See, changes in classes are applied *after* digest - and that's after `numItems()` is evaluated, hence the delay in demo mentioned by @Thirumalaimurugan.

A quick-and-dirty solution is using another attribute for selector in numItems (in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7mPZRezz1zAPN5L6eWuQ?p=preview), it's `data-color`). But I would strongly advise you against it. The proper approach would be adding the data rendered by `numItems()` -using component into the model. For example:

**app.js**

```
// ...
var colorScheme = {
  'toggle':  {true: 'yellow', false: 'red'},
  'toggle2': {true: 'green', false: 'red'},
  'toggle3': {true: 'green', false: 'red'},
  'toggle4': {true: 'red', false: 'green'}
};

$scope.getColor = function getColor(param) {
  return colorScheme[param][$scope[param]];
};

$scope.countColor = function(color) {
  return Object.keys(colorScheme).filter(function(key) {
    return colorScheme[key][$scope[key]] === color;
  }).length;
};
```

**index.html**

```
<p ng-class="getColor('toggle')">{{name}}</p>
<!-- ... -->

<p ng-repeat="color in ['Yellow', 'Green', 'Red']" 
   ng-bind="color + ' ' + countColor(color.toLowerCase())">
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/pIbBAy1hnY7KylY0UvJU?p=preview).

Comment: In angularjs 1.4.8 version its not working as expected? can you please check http://plnkr.co/edit/g6fa6waeg0HSH29aYgnN?p=preview

Comment: [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7mPZRezz1zAPN5L6eWuQ?p=preview) I (sort of) fixed it. Overall, the OP's intent - track changes in the view, not in the model - wasn't a good idea from the very beginning, that's why it was easily broken when AngularJS team optimized handling of class changes. I'll update my answer with explanation a bit later.